# Chrome Remote DevTools Connection Drops after few minutes

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, adb, chrome-remote-debugging

I am using chrome://inspect/?#devices to connect with my android device.

After ~20 minutes my device gets disconnected automatically every single time.
After it gets discontinued my device asks for allowing usb device again. And if I run `adb devices` on my Mac, I am unable to see my device since it got disconnected.

I wanted to know the why this is happening and is there a fix available for this or not.

Aim: I want to connect my android device at least for 3 hours without interruption.

I have tried this with multiple devices, multiple data cable and multiple physical conditions but I don't think the issue is from hardware side. USB Debugging is on and the connection stays for a few minutes without any issue, everything works fine for some minutes(not fixed but it is around 20 minutes).

Adding images of my android device and macbook after the connection gets disconnected:
[image: Image of chrome on macbook]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing similar issues then here are the things that you can try:

1. Try different USB cable(s)
2. Try different USB ports on your machine(for some people using 2.0 port worked out)
3. Try the same process, with unchecked 'Discover USB Devices' in chrome://inspect (then Chrome will connect through the ADB server, not directly) ==> This solution worked in my scenario.